# How can I write to a global variable in Aurelia?

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, aurelia

I'm writing an Aurelia application and I have registered an instance of a class inside the aurelia container.  Now, when I authenticate a user, that instance has to be modified.  How do I modify the original instance from anywhere in my code?

Comment: I know you're just aching to review the answers below. One of them is *really* good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I modify the original instance from anywhere in my code

Best that put the instance in a module. And then also expose functions that modify the instance. e.g.

```
let foo = {}

export function getFoo(){return foo}
export function setFoo(bar){ /* do something */}
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want to follow the dependency injection pattern, you need to inject that instance into any class that wants to modify the instance.

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework'
import { MyClass } from './my-class';

@inject(MyClass)
export class MyViewModel {
    constructor(MyClass) {
        this.myClass = MyClass;
    }
    somethingSpecial() {
        this.myClass.foo = 'bar';
    }
}
```

Comment: if the answer was helpful, upvote and accept please!

Comment: This is the correct answer. By default Aurelia's dependency injection treats all imports (except custom elements and attributes) as singletons.  You can even go further and import the `Container` itself and use that to get a class from a function, etc.

Comment: this is helpful but how does one cope with properties set asynchronously in MyClass?